# Unable to display MultiSelectList.SelectedValues on MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-multiselect

I am working with a `MVC` application that is legacy code. So far, the changes I made are the 2 calls to retrieve the lists of `AccountDivisionModel` objects. The original code called the stored procedures and returned an `ObjectResult`, which contained the data.

```
public class AccountDivisionModel
{
    int DivisionID;
    string DivisionName;
    int AccountID;
    bool IsActive;
}
```

I'm making 2 calls to retrieve a list of divisions that belong to an account and a list of (selected) divisions that belong to a contact of the account.

```
var aDivs = Account.GetDivisionByAccountID(c.AccountID).ToArray();
var cDivs = Contact.GetDivisionByContactID(c.ContactID).ToArray();
ViewBag.AccountDivisions = new MultiSelectList(aDivs, "DivisionID", "DivisionName", cDivs);
```

In my Edit view

```
@Html.DropDownList("AccountDivisions", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @multiple = "multiple", @placeholder = "Select Division(s)" })
```

I don't know why the `SelectedValues` is not showing even though when I click on the text box (@placeholder), I can see it populate the drop down list with all divisions.

What have I done wrong?

Below is the image of the current working interface. As you can see, the Selected Values displayed in the box and the drop down list showing the remaining items that have not been selected.

[image: image of the current working interface]

Comment: Do you mean you expect to see some of the options pre-selected in the list based on some value?

Comment: Yes. Whenever I come to this page, I would see divisions I have added to the contact previously. And I could add more divisions from the drop down list or remove pre-selected divisions.

Comment: The overload you are using to create the `MultiSelectList` accepts an collection of selected values. Since your using property `DivisionID` as the option value (I assume this is `int`), so the last parameter should be `IEnumerable<int>` that contains values you want to be selected. But you really should consider using a view model with a property like `int[] SelectedDivisions` and bind to that using @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedDivisions, Model.AccountDivisions)` so you get all the proper behavior out of the box.

Comment: That's it, Stephen. The cDivs needs to be a List<int>, not a collection of (DivisionIDs and DivisionNames). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 4th argument of `MultiSelectList` needs to a collection of the selected values (usually `int` or `string`) which match the type of the second parameter. Currently you are passing it a collection of complex objects so it does not match any option value. Your could solve this by changing

```
var cDivs = Contact.GetDivisionByContactID(c.ContactID).ToArray();
```

to

```
var cDivs = Contact.GetDivisionByContactID(c.ContactID).Select(c => c.DivisionIDs);
```

However I would recommend including a property in your model representing the selected divisions that allows 2 way binding

Model

```
public IEnumerable<int> SelectedDivisions { get; set; }
```

Controller

```
model.SelectedDivisions = Contact.GetDivisionByContactID(c.ContactID).Select(c => c.DivisionID);
ViewBag.AccountDivisions = new MultiSelectList(aDivs, "DivisionID", "DivisionName"); // 4th parameter not required
```

View

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedDivisions, (MultiSelectList)ViewBag.AccountDivisions, new { @class = "form-control"}) // ListBoxFor adds multiple attribute
```

The model then contains the selected values on post back.

Answer (score 0):

you do not need the `@` for all the HTML Attributes, you only need it for class , because that is a reserved word in c#

```
@Html.DropDownList("AccountDivisions", null, htmlAttributes: new 
       { @class = "form-control", multiple = "multiple", placeholder = "Select Division(s)" })
```

You may be doing this all wrong , the typical use for a DropDown is for users to choose one option out of a bunch of options.  So Typically a Model will have 2 properities , something like:

```
List<SelectItems> Accounts
int SelectedAccount
```

then.. you would do

```
@Html.DropDownListFor( x => x.SelectedAccount, (SelectList)x.Accounts)
```

Comment: I have not changed anything of the view. I only changed the code at the Controller level, so I suspect I did something wrong there. I have included the image of the current working interface above. I believe bootstrap is being used in the view as well, if that adds any clarification.